# Representation of Lie algebra of germs of smooth/holomorphic functions

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

$\def\O{\mathcal{O}}
\def\g{\mathfrak{g}}$
Suppose $G$ is a real or complex Lie group, with Lie algebra $\g$. Write $\O_{G,1}$ (resp. $\O_{\g,0}$) for the ring of germs of smooth/holomorphic function on $G$ at $1$ (resp. on $\g$ at $0$). If we identify $\g$ with left-invariant vector fields on $G$, then we get a Lie algebra representation of $\g$ on $\O_{G,1}$. The exponential map $\exp:\g \to G$ is a local isomorphism, so induces an isomorphism of $\O_{\g,0}$ and $\O_{G,1}$, so we also get a Lie algebra representation of $\g$ on $\O_{\g,0}$.

Can the representation of $\g$ on $\O_{\g,0}$ be described in a way that is intrinsic to $\g$, without reference $G$?

Comment: I think it might be more or less the dual of the adjoint action of $\mathfrak{g}$ on its universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$.